# How to check EU VAT using VIES SOAP service in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

I have an ASP.NET website that needs to check a user-supplied VAT. The [VIES Service](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/) can be used for that which exposes a [SOAP API](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/technicalInformation.html).

I need a dead-simple example on how to validate a VAT using this service. In PHP, it's these 4 lines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14340495. For C#, I have found some articles from 2010 that do not work or are tens or even hundreds lines of "wrappers", "helper services" etc.

I don't need any of that, can someone provide PHP-like four-liner that would check VAT in C#? Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a self-sufficient (no WCF, no WSDL, ...) utility class that will check the VAT number and get information on the company (name and address). It will return null if the VAT number is invalid or if any error occurred.

**Update 2022/10/17** : I have added namespace handling to parse the response as it seems the EU web service was modified. If you need the old version, just look at the history

```
// sample calling code
Console.WriteLine(EuropeanVatInformation.Get("FR89831948815"));

...

public class EuropeanVatInformation
{
    private EuropeanVatInformation() { }

    public string CountryCode { get; private set; }
    public string VatNumber { get; private set; }
    public string Address { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public override string ToString() => CountryCode + " " + VatNumber + ": " + Name + ", " + Address.Replace("\n", ", ");

    public static EuropeanVatInformation Get(string countryCodeAndVatNumber)
    {
        if (countryCodeAndVatNumber == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(countryCodeAndVatNumber));

        if (countryCodeAndVatNumber.Length < 3)
            return null;

        return Get(countryCodeAndVatNumber.Substring(0, 2), countryCodeAndVatNumber.Substring(2));
    }

    public static EuropeanVatInformation Get(string countryCode, string vatNumber)
    {
        if (countryCode == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(countryCode));

        if (vatNumber == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(vatNumber));

        countryCode = countryCode.Trim();
        vatNumber = vatNumber.Trim().Replace(" ", string.Empty);

        const string ns = "urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types";
        const string url = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService";
        const string xml = @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><s:Body><checkVat xmlns='" + ns + "'><countryCode>{0}</countryCode><vatNumber>{1}</vatNumber></checkVat></s:Body></s:Envelope>";

        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(client.UploadString(url, string.Format(xml, countryCode, vatNumber)));
                var response = doc.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='checkVatResponse']") as XmlElement;
                if (response == null || response["valid", ns]?.InnerText != "true")
                    return null;

                var info = new EuropeanVatInformation
                {
                    CountryCode = response["countryCode", ns].InnerText,
                    VatNumber = response["vatNumber", ns].InnerText,
                    Name = response["name", ns]?.InnerText,
                    Address = response["address", ns]?.InnerText
                };
                return info;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Three years on, this was the most reliable answer for me. Thanks!

Comment: This is also a valid approach if you are deploying to OpenShift. We had issues using connected services in this hosting scenario. Going "raw" path works.

Comment: Trying to use this anwser and for the most part it works. I mean I gets the result from the service as expected but I is not able to resolve the response["valid"]?.InnerText != "true". There is a 'valid' element in the response but code still evaluates to false. Why is that? It is as if the 'response' does not match the expected result?

Comment: @Holm76 - It's a late answer to your comment but I have updated the answer.

Comment: I want to give this another upvote nearly two years on because I've spent the last two hours trying to figure out why this had stopped working, and found your answer again. Thanks for the recent fix!

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way I found is just to send an XML and parse it when it comes back:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var request = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:urn=""urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types"">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:checkVat>
         <urn:countryCode>COUNTRY</urn:countryCode>
         <urn:vatNumber>VATNUMBER</urn:vatNumber>
      </urn:checkVat>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>";

request = request.Replace("COUNTRY", countryCode);
request = request.Replace("VATNUMBER", theRest);

String response;
try
{
    response = wc.UploadString("http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService", request);
}
catch
{
    // service throws WebException e.g. when non-EU VAT is supplied
}

var isValid = response.Contains("<valid>true</valid>");
```

Comment: what is WC for type? how and what's declared with this?

Comment: added >> var wc = new WebClient();

Answer (score 6):

On .NET platform it is common to consume a Web service so that we generate a proxy class. This can usually be done using Visual Studio "Add Web Reference" where you just fill in a path to the WSDL. An alternative is to generate source classes using [wsdl.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx) or [svcutil.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx).

Then just consume this class and verifying VAT becomes a one-liner:

```
DateTime date = new checkVatPortTypeClient().checkVat(ref countryCode, ref vatNumber, out isValid, out name, out address);
```

Generating proxy provides strongly typed API to consume whole service and we don't need to manually create soap envelope and parse output text. It is much more easier, safer and generic solution than [yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33169331/519856).

Comment: I guess this answer is outdated since the service does not provide a checkVat function anymore.

Comment: @Ben So the OP answer is outdated too. But my answer is still valid because you can simply regenerate proxy class and properly update calling code.

Answer (score 5):

Updated: I've published this as a NuGet library.

https://github.com/TriggerMe/CSharpVatChecker

```cs
var vatQuery = new VATQuery();
var vatResult = await vatQuery.CheckVATNumberAsync("IE", "3041081MH"); // The Squarespace VAT Number

Console.WriteLine(vatResult.Valid); // Is the VAT Number valid?
Console.WriteLine(vatResult.Name);  // Name of the organisation
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Pavel Hodek's:

1. Make sure you have the [Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference
   Provide](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WCFCORETEAM.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService) extension installed for visual studio (I'm using VS 2017
   Community).
2. In the solution explorer right click on Connected Services > Add Connected Service
3. Select the WCF extension.
4. Type in the URL provided by VIES
   http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl to generate the Service class from the wsdl.
5. Press Go and select the service, give a proper name for the namespace e.g. Services.VATCheck
6. Press Finish, which will create a new folder and a file called `reference.cs` in the Connected Services rename the file to VATCheck which will also rename the Class.

In a controller use the following code to invoke the call, make sure it's async (it can take awhile to eventually load all the data)

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> CheckVAT()
    {
        var countryCode = "BE";
        var vatNumber = "123456789";

        try
        {
            checkVatPortType test = new checkVatPortTypeClient(checkVatPortTypeClient.EndpointConfiguration.checkVatPort, "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService");
            checkVatResponse response = await test.checkVatAsync(new checkVatRequest { countryCode = countryCode, vatNumber = vatNumber });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Please note that you can clean-up this call, but that's totally up to you.

Comment: probably the best answer as it uses the supported method provided by the EU who is providing the wsdl. this highlights the documentation that's missing stating you need to provide the port and url, this is where all the developers get stuck

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BTWCheck.eu.europa.ec;    

namespace BTWCheck
{
     class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // VS 2017
            // add service reference -> button "Advanced" -> button "Add Web Reference" ->
            // URL = http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl 

            string Landcode = "NL";
            string BTWNummer = "820471616B01"; // VAT nr BOL.COM 

            checkVatService test = new checkVatService();
            test.checkVat(ref Landcode, ref BTWNummer, out bool GeldigBTWNr, out string Naam, out string Adres);

            Console.WriteLine(Landcode + BTWNummer + " " + GeldigBTWNr);
            Console.WriteLine(Naam+Adres);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please write some comments/descriptions to your answer to improve it.