# vb.net use checkVatService.wsdl

Tags: vb.net

http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl
to check VAT in Italy.
I wrote this

```
Public Function check_piva() As Date
    Dim pivawe As New checkvatService.europa.ec.checkVatService
    Dim piva As String = "0798012121lk9"
    Dim bb As Boolean
    Dim s As String
    Dim n As String = String.Empty
    Dim data As Date
    data = pivawe.checkVat("IT", piva, bb, n, n)
    MsgBox(data)
    Return data
```

It always return todays data if vat is either wrong or correct , I don-t either understand why a `checkVAt` function gives back a date not a string or boolean

I saw they also have `checkVatAsync`

```
Dim pivawe As New checkvatService.europa.ec.checkVatService
Dim piva As String = "0798012121lk9"
Dim bb As Boolean
Dim s As String
Dim n As String = String.Empty
Dim data As Date
pivawe.checkVatAsync("IT", piva)
MsgBox(data)
Return data
```

This runs no error but I don-t get a value back. If I write

```
s = pivawe.checkVatAsync("IT", piva)
```

I get error

> expression does not produce value.

May be web service simply does not work.
Any suggestion thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to archive but let's say if you need to validate a VAT number. Then you only need to consume it. In the below example I am passing the COUNTRY and VAT number immediately in the soap request but you can easily do string concatenation and pass dynamic variables there.

```
Imports System.Net

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

        Dim request As String = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:urn=""urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types"">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
              <urn:checkVat>
                 <urn:countryCode>IT</urn:countryCode>
                 <urn:vatNumber>XXXXXXXXXXX</urn:vatNumber>
              </urn:checkVat>
            </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>"

        Dim response As String = ""

        Try
            response = client.UploadString("http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService", request)
        Catch
            Console.WriteLine("Exception")
            'service throws WebException e.g. when non-EU VAT Is supplied
        End Try

        Console.WriteLine(response)
        Console.WriteLine("")

        If response.Contains("<valid>true</valid>") Then
            Console.WriteLine("VALID")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("NOT")
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

This will consume the SOAP and reply whether the VAT is valid in that country or not. XXXXXXXXXXX = Vat Number ;) Also you can turn them into variables as this excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168424/how-to-check-eu-vat-using-vies-soap-service-in-c-sharp) by Borek has!